# Firefox Border CSS Issue

Tags: jquery, css, firefox, border

In Firefox, when I try to remove a border of a table cell with jQuery

```
jQuery(td-selector).css({'border' : 'none'});
```

It still shows up a weird border on some (not all edges) of the table cell.  When I try to inspect the cell with Firebug, the border disappears.

Has anyone else run into the same issue?

Comment: Sounds to me like its related to another firefox plugin. `'none'` should do the trick in all browsers

Comment: Have you check borders on TD, TR and TABLE element ?

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a jsFiddle? http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: There is no border on the TR or TABLE element, just on the TD element.
I've tried setting borderWidth to 0px but still doesnt work on Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS:

```css
table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

[MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/border-collapse)

Comment: I created a jsFiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/RqWVG/1/ which this does not happen in so I can't replicate your issue. Either update that fiddle or create your own where we can see the problem at hand.